# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ResolvableTypeProvider

Tags: spring, maven

I have project1, which has a dependency on project2, which has a dependency on project3 ( project1 -> project2 -> project3).

spring versions used in the mentioned pom.xml

project1 pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <spring.core.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.core.version>
        <build.env>dev</build.env>
        <cxf.version>2.3.0</cxf.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

project2 pom.xml

```
<properties>
              <spring.orm.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.orm.version>
              <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

project 3 pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <spring.core.version>4.3.10.RELEASE</spring.core.version>
        <spring.orm.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.orm.version>
 </properties>
```

I am getting following below error:

```
2018-04-16 09:52:53,376 ERROR localhost-startStop-4 [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ResolvableTypeProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2004)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:379)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ResolvableTypeProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Never mix versions of a framework (regardless of a framework) you are mixing 4 versions of Spring (3.1.2, 3.24, 4.1.6 and 4.3.10) and expect them to work together that isn't going to happen. Use a single version for jars of a framework don't mix (unless you want weird to debug issues and strange stack traces).

Answer (score 0):

Your spring dependencies version are a mess, you should have the same version in all modules. otherwise if those version are a requirements you have to check which version is compatible with the other